# Mapping a macro onto multiple lists simultaneously

Tags: macros, comma-separated-list

I have a macro (say `\myMacro`) that takes three arguments (say a, b, c) and I want to write another macro (say `\otherMacro`) that given three lists of parameters (comma delimited lists and all of the same length and the length of the lists is two or more)  maps `\myMacro` onto these arguments in turn. That is

```
\otherMacro {a1, a2, a3}{b1, b2, b3}{c1, c2, c3}
```

gives the representation

```
\myMacro{a1}{b1}{c1} \mapsto
  (\myMacro{a2}{b2}{c2} , \myMacro{a3}{b3}{c3})
```

and

```
\otherMacro {a1, a2, a3, a4}{b1, b2, b3, b4}{c1, c2, c3, c4}
```

gives the representation

```
\myMacro{a1}{b1}{c1} \mapsto
  (\myMacro{a2}{b2}{c2} , \myMacro{a3}{b3}{c3}, \myMacro{a4}{b4}{c4})
```

I am a LaTeX novice and I am very sorry if similar questions have already been asked. I searched the site and found problems that were somewhat similar but I couldn't make sense of the solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rather crude version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcount\my@index
\newcommand\otherMacro[3]
{%
  \my@index\z@
  \@othermacro#1,\@nil#2,\@nil#3,\@nil
}
\def\@othermacro#1,#2\@nil#3,#4\@nil#5,#6\@nil
{%
  \ifnum\my@index=\@ne\mapsto (\fi
  \ifnum\my@index>\@ne,\fi
  \myMacro{#1}{#3}{#5}%
  \ifx\empty#2\empty
    )%
   \else
    \advance\my@index\@ne
    \@othermacro#2\@nil#4\@nil#6\@nil
  \fi
}
\newcommand\myMacro[3]{\max(#1,#2,#3)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\otherMacro {a1,a2,a3,a4}{b1,b2,b3,b4}{c1,c2,c3,c4}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: @stephen-lehmke Thank you again. I had never seen this syntax before (e.g. \@ne, \my@index, etc.) I was wondering if you could tell me where I can read more about this?

Comment: In principle you'll find all you need to know in the TeXbook by Donald E. Knuth. The macro names with `@` in them are not a special "notation" though but just a convention for writing "internal" macro or counter names. Normally `@` is not a letter, so names with `@` in them can not be used. In packages, this is allowed, or if it is explicitly turned on (as I did) with `\makeatletter`. `\@ne` is simply a predefined name denoting "1".

Answer (score 4):

This works for arbitrarily long lists (at least two elements, of course):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\myMacro}[3]{[#1,#2,#3]} % define suitably

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\otherMacro}{mmm}{ \maps_splitargs:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3} }

\seq_new:N \l_maps_first_seq
\seq_new:N \l_maps_second_seq
\seq_new:N \l_maps_third_seq

\cs_new:Npn \maps_splitargs:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_maps_first_seq  {,} { #1 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_maps_second_seq {,} { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_maps_third_seq  {,} { #3 }
  \prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { \seq_length:N \l_maps_first_seq - 1 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
     {
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_maps_first_seq { ##1 } }
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_maps_second_seq { ##1 } }
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_maps_third_seq { ##1 } }
     }
    \exp_after:wN \myMacro \l_tmpa_tl
    \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = 0 }
     { \mapsto ( }
     { \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = \seq_length:N \l_maps_first_seq - 1 } { ) } { , } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$\otherMacro {a1,a2}{b1,b2}{c1,c2}$

$\otherMacro {a1,a2,a3}{b1,b2,b3}{c1,c2,c3}$

$\otherMacro {a1,a2,a3,a4}{b1,b2,b3,b4}{c1,c2,c3,c4}$

$\otherMacro {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5}{b1,b2,b3,b4,b5}{c1,c2,c3,c4,c5}$

\end{document}
```

---

### Important change

Due to the changes made to `expl3` in Summer 2012, the code above should be replaced by the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\myMacro}[3]{[#1,#2,#3]} % define suitably

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\otherMacro}{mmm}{ \maps_splitargs:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3} }

\seq_new:N \l_maps_first_seq
\seq_new:N \l_maps_second_seq
\seq_new:N \l_maps_third_seq

\cs_new:Npn \maps_splitargs:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_maps_first_seq  {,} { #1 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_maps_second_seq {,} { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_maps_third_seq  {,} { #3 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_maps_first_seq }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
     {
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_maps_first_seq { ##1 } }
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_maps_second_seq { ##1 } }
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_maps_third_seq { ##1 } }
     }
    \exp_after:wN \myMacro \l_tmpa_tl
    \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = 1 }
     { \mapsto ( }
     { \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = \seq_count:N \l_maps_first_seq } { ) } { , } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$\otherMacro {a1,a2}{b1,b2}{c1,c2}$

$\otherMacro {a1,a2,a3}{b1,b2,b3}{c1,c2,c3}$

$\otherMacro {a1,a2,a3,a4}{b1,b2,b3,b4}{c1,c2,c3,c4}$

$\otherMacro {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5}{b1,b2,b3,b4,b5}{c1,c2,c3,c4,c5}$

\end{document}
```